# The Clock and TrivialClock concepts in the chrono library

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, c++-chrono, c++-concepts

The `std::chrono` library relies, in part, on the concept of a [Clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Clock) and a [TrivialClock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialClock). I went through the standard, but I am still not sure about a few things:

- Is the only difference between `Clock` and `TrivialClock`, the fact that `now` may throw for a `Clock`, but does not for a `TrivialClock`?
- Is `clock::duration` required to be the same as `clock::time_point::duration?`
- Is `now` required to be a static function member, or not?

References/quotes to the standard are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Is the only difference between `Clock` and `TrivialClock`, the fact that now may throw for a `Clock`, but does not for a `TrivialClock`?

No. There are also more requirements on the member types of `TrivialClock`. A clock with a `const int` as its `rep` is not a `TrivialClock`, but it is a `Clock`.

> - Is `clock::duration` required to be the same as `clock::time_point::duration`?

Yes. The two possible instantiations are `std::time_point<clock>`, which has `clock::duration` from the default parameter; or `std::time_point<other_clock, clock::duration>`, which has it explicitly.

> - Is `now` required to be a static function member, or not?

Not as far as I can tell, but people are likely to assume that it is. All that is required is for `clock::now()` to be a valid expression, which returns a `clock::time_point`. It could be a static functor.